# How can I make an object visible only on the minimap in GameMaker?

Tags: game-maker

I am making a game in which I have created a minimap using views. I want in the minimap (the copy of the world) to add an object, but I want it to be visible *only* from the minimap. Is there any way to do this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *Draw Event* of the object you want to draw in the minimap only, if the minimap has `view` index `1` (assuming the main `view` with index `0` is what the player is actually seeing) you can simply write:

```
// Draw event for minimap-only object
if (view_current==1)
{
    // Draw event for this object
    // for minimap only (view 1)
}
else
{
    // Draw onto any other view (only if needed)
}
```

This way the *Draw Event* of your object will draw only in the `view` with index `1`, your minimap.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an object that exists in the game as well, even while it's not visible? If so then could you use that object to draw a sprite on the mini-map?

Comment: Yeah, it IS an object that is visible from the minimap. But, as I said it is located on the minimap area and as a result, it is visible also from the main view, so I want to make it visible ONLY from the minimap.

Comment: Hrmm, could you possibly post a screenshot? Sorry, but I'm having a hard time fully understanding what you mean.